# What does this に imply?

Tags: particle-に, passive-voice

せっかくの休みに、あなほり　なんかやらされて。。。

In a ドラえもん comic, someone said this and took a break from digging a hole in the ground.

I understand the sentence generally (probably), but not enough grammatically, and not enough to say something like that.

First, I guess やらされる means "I am being made to (do this digging)." Since it ends with て、I think the 。。。could have replaced something like "and I'm tired."

Because of that, he decides to rest. I used google a little bit, and saw a little of 休みになる、休みに入る。This only adds to my confusion. (Articles I saw seemed to talk about doing stuff while on rest.)

Am I going about this wrong? What would follow this に？ Or, why not use the verb 休む？

よろしくおねがいします

Comment: Have you considered that it could be on his day off?

Comment: Oh wow. I don't really know, but later on he gets in trouble and says this: ひと休みして、またほるよ。So, maybe I would say it's not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be "seeing" something that is just not there.  The 「に」 implies nothing.

「休{やす}み」 is a ***noun*** meaning a "holiday", "day off", etc.  It could not be a verb when it follows an adjectival phrase like 「せっかく**の**」("***long-awaited***").

**「休みに」＝「休みの日に」**

Thus, the 「に」 is a simple time-marker.  We say 「休み**に**」、「夏休{なつやす}み**に**」「日曜日**に**」、「2020年**に**」, etc.

> First, I guess やらされる means "I am being made to (do this digging)." Since it ends with て、I think the 。。。could have replaced something like "and I'm tired."

Precisely.  「やらされる」 is the passive-causative expressing the speaker's "suffering".

> "***I am being forced to do something like digging a hole on a long-awaited holiday and .....***"

is both the literal meaning and the "feel" of the sentence.

You should naturally expect a verb phrase to follow a 「休みに」.